# how do I fix this name error that im getting for a variable?

Tags: python

I am getting this name error: NameError: name 'Confirm_password' is not defined

it works fine when i choose sign up, but it gives me the error for when i choose to login, I do not know what the problem is, I already have the variable defined so what's the problem? sorry if it seems dumb i'm new to coding.

this is my code:

```
from os import system


question = input("sign up or login? ")

if question.lower() == ("sign up"):
    email = input("Enter Email Address: ")
    Username = input("Username: ")
    Password = input("Password: ")
    Confirm_password = input("Confirm Password: ")

if Confirm_password.lower() != Password:
    print("incorrect password")
else:
    print("Account Created!")


if question.lower() == ("login"):
    login_email = input("Enter Email address or username: ")
    login_password = input("Enter Password: ")
```

Comment: move that `if`/`else` inside first `if` condition

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the `if/else` block inside the if statement. Only then `Confirm_password` will get defined. Updated code:

```
from os import system


question = input("sign up or login? ")

if question.lower() == ("sign up"):
    email = input("Enter Email Address: ")
    Username = input("Username: ")
    Password = input("Password: ")
    Confirm_password = input("Confirm Password: ")

    if Confirm_password.lower() != Password: # You need to move this inside if statement.
        print("incorrect password")
    else:
        print("Account Created!")


elif question.lower() == ("login"):
    login_email = input("Enter Email address or username: ")
    login_password = input("Enter Password: ")
```